# Visual Studio 6 C ++ error C2011 with msxml

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-6

I have inherited an old Visual Studio 6 C++ program.  I have a Windows 7 computer.  I have installed an XP virtual machine on my computer.  Visual Studio 6 and service pack 6 has been installed.  I am trying to build the .exe file in debug mode.  I continue to get the error

```
C2011: 'IXMLDOMImplementation' : 'struct' type redefinition in msxml4.tlh file.
```

The errors are occurring for all struct and enum definitions.  KB 269194 states If a newer version of MSXML has been installed in side-by-side mode, you must explicitly use the Globally Unique Identifiers (GUIDs) or ProgIDs for that version to run the sample code.  The GUID is specified using declspec(uuid()) as below.
  struct __declspec(uuid("50ea08b0-dd1b-4664-9a50-c2f40f4bd79a"))
IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2 : IXMLDOMSchemaCollection
{
I do not believe I should have to make any code changes.  I have installed MSXML4 on the virtual machine.  KB article 269194 discusses the problem.  It does not help.

The files msxml4.h, msxml4.cpp, msxml4.dll, msxml4.tlh and msxml.tli are all in the project directory. I did install MSXML4 on my virtual XP machine.   I have added these files to the include path in Visual Studio for this workspace.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible. Some environment request very tested (and old by consequence) operating system, compiler and so on, or software that's certified and re-certified again with new software will be very expensive.

Comment: There are some pointers there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980082/error-c2011-msxml2ixmldomimplementation-struct-type-redefinition . My guess : try to locate every include/import statement to msxml3, which might clash with the 4.0.

Comment: My coworker fixed the problem.  First, do a build clean.  Second, build the EXE file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the combination of #import xml and /MP multi-processor compile.
The two are not compatible.
Identify any modules that have the #import.  Build them WITHOUT the /MP switch.
The other modules can safely use the /MP switch.